# Default timeout value of istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway, istio-operator

I have a service in which i have added a delay of 5 minutes. So the request to this service will take 5 minutes to give the response.
Now I have deployed this service in kubernetes with istio v1.5. When I am calling this service through the ingress gateway, I am getting a timeout in 3 minutes.

```
{"res_tx_duration":"-","route_name":"default","user_agent":"grpc-java-netty/1.29.0","response_code_details":"-","start_time":"****","request_id":"****","method":"POST","upstream_host":"127.0.0.1:6565","x_forwarded_for":"****","bytes_sent":"0","upstream_cluster":"****","downstream_remote_address":"****","req_duration":"0","path":"/****","authority":"****","protocol":"HTTP/2","upstream_service_time":"-","upstream_local_address":"-","duration":"180000","upstream_transport_failure_reason":"-","response_code":"0","res_duration":"-","response_flags":"DC","bytes_received":"5"}
```

I tried to set the timeout in the Virtual service greater than the 3 minutes, but that is not working. Only the timeouts less than 3 minutes set in the virtual service is working.

```
route:
- destination:
    host: demo-service
    port:
      number: 8000
timeout: 240s
```

Is there any other configuration where we can set the timeout, other than VirtualService?

Is 3 minutes (180s) is the maximum value we can set in the VirtualService?

Comment: did you figure out how to solve this?